# How to have a user select a value from array and pass that into a variable in KSH

Tags: arrays, shell, variables, user-input, ksh

**Overview:**

I would like my KSH script to test for the presence of certain files in a directory, present the user with a list of those files along with a number.  The user then chooses the number they want and the relevant value from the array is assigned to a variable.

So far I have the following:

```
### Create test files in directory ####
touch ABCDEF.jar
touch BCDEFG.jar
touch CDEFGH.jar
touch DEFGHI.jar
touch EFGHIJ.jar
touch FGHIJK.jar
touch GHIJKL.jar


set -A JARS ` ls -1 | grep .jar | cut -d'.' --complement -f2-`
for i in ${JARS[@]}; do echo "Number) $i"; done
```

This returns the following list from the array:

```
Number) ABCDEF
Number) BCDEFG
Number) CDEFGH
Number) DEFGHI
Number) EFGHIJ
Number) FGHIJK
Number) GHIJKL
```

Firstly, I'd like to replace the place holder "Number)" with a function which increases the number in sequence to get something like this:

```
1) ABCDEF
2) BCDEFG
3) CDEFGH
4) DEFGHI
5) EFGHIJ
6) FGHIJK
7) GHIJKL
```

I'd then like to have the script read the user input based on the Number the user has chosen, and assign the correct value from the array to a new variable "JAR_ID"

On the face of it, it seems like a simple problem.  However, I just can't seem to get my head round how to do this in a logical way.

Any ideas gratefully appreciated!

TIA
Huskie.

Comment: http://ps-2.kev009.com/AIXtip/select.htm

Comment: I didn't realise Korn had this feature for building selection menus!  However, how would I handle the fact that the array is dynamically generated?

Comment: `select file from *.jar`

Comment: I'm not sure 'select' on my system does the same thing -  man select
SELECT(2)                  Linux Programmer’s Manual                 SELECT(2)

NAME
       select, pselect, FD_CLR, FD_ISSET, FD_SET, FD_ZERO - synchronous I/O multiplexing    select()  and  pselect()  allow  a  program to monitor multiple file descriptors, waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready" for some
       class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible).  A file descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform the corresponding I/O  operation  (e.g.,
       read(2)) without blocking.

Comment: This isn't `select(2)`. This is `select` the shell built-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind the full filenames in the list then just this will work.

```
select JAR in *.jar; do
        export NEW_PATCHID=$JAR
        echo $NEW_PATCHID
        REPLY=''
        break
done
```

If you do mind (and the example indicates you might) and you want to drop `.jar` (I'm assuming that's what that `cut` is for though `cut -d. -f1` would seem simpler for that as would `awk -F . '{print $1}'` though that is longer) the following works safely.

```
jars=(*.jar)
select JAR in "${jars[@]%.jar}"; do
        export NEW_PATCHID=$JAR
        echo $NEW_PATCHID
        REPLY=''
        break
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Etan's poke in the right direction, I was able to do what I needed using the following code:

```
#!/bin/ksh

type_prompt='Select JAR> '
PS3="${type_prompt}"

select JAR in `ls -1 | grep .jar | cut -d'.' --complement -f2-` QUIT
do
        export NEW_PATCHID=$JAR
        echo $NEW_PATCHID
        REPLY=''
        break
done
```

This is exactly what I needed and works in the way I want.  Thanks again Etan

Comment: You do *not* want to be using `ls` like that. You also don't need to. If a plain glob `*.jar` in that line doesn't work (because it contains too much). You can expand that glob into an array `jars=(*.jar)` and then use shell variable expansion or a loop to manipulate the strings to your desired format and then `select JAR in "${jars[@]}"` for that line.

Comment: Thanks Etan.  I'll take this on board.  I'm still a relative newb as far as the dynamics of shell scripting goes and appreciate the advice.